GPIO not working on Debian kernel
Years ago, I installed Debian with UEFI on a Raspberry Pi 4 8Gio by following this tutorial. I never got the GPIO to work, but now I need them. I'm currently on Debian Bookworm.
There is no GPIO chip in /sys/class/gpio:
$ ls /sys/class/gpio
export  unexport

And neither in /dev/gpiochip*.
Trying to export a pin doesn't work:
$ echo 13 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo: write error: invalid argument

gpioinfo normally exits, but doesn't output anything:
$ apt install gpiod
...
$ gpioinfo
$ echo $?
0

lsmod | grep gpio doesn't show anything and trying to load gpio doesn't work:
$ modprobe gpio
modprobe: FATAL: Module gpio not found in directory /lib/modules/6.1.0-20-arm64

Running dmesg after boot shows some lines related to GPIO. But from what I understand this is linked to Bluetooth, so unrelated:
[    5.220699] hci_uart_bcm serial0-0: Unexpected ACPI gpio_int_idx: -1
[    5.220708] hci_uart_bcm serial0-0: Unexpected number of ACPI GPIOs: 0
[    5.220786] hci_uart_bcm serial0-0: supply vbat not found, using dummy regulator

Here is an extract of /boot/config-6.1.0-20-arm64:
CONFIG_GPIOLIB=y
CONFIG_GPIOLIB_FASTPATH_LIMIT=512
CONFIG_OF_GPIO=y
CONFIG_GPIO_ACPI=y
CONFIG_GPIOLIB_IRQCHIP=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_GPIO is not set
CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_GPIO_CDEV=y
CONFIG_GPIO_CDEV_V1=y
CONFIG_GPIO_GENERIC=y
CONFIG_GPIO_REGMAP=m

#
# Memory mapped GPIO drivers
#
# CONFIG_GPIO_74XX_MMIO is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_ALTERA is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_AMDPT is not set
CONFIG_GPIO_RASPBERRYPI_EXP=y
# CONFIG_GPIO_CADENCE is not set
CONFIG_GPIO_DAVINCI=y
# CONFIG_GPIO_DWAPB is not set
CONFIG_GPIO_EXAR=m
# CONFIG_GPIO_FTGPIO010 is not set
CONFIG_GPIO_GENERIC_PLATFORM=y
# CONFIG_GPIO_GRGPIO is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_HISI is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_HLWD is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_LOGICVC is not set  
CONFIG_GPIO_MB86S7X=m  
CONFIG_GPIO_MPC8XXX=y   
CONFIG_GPIO_MVEBU=y
CONFIG_GPIO_MXC=y
CONFIG_GPIO_PL061=y
CONFIG_GPIO_RCAR=m
CONFIG_GPIO_ROCKCHIP=y
# CONFIG_GPIO_SIFIVE is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_SYSCON is not set
CONFIG_GPIO_TEGRA=y
# CONFIG_GPIO_THUNDERX is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_VF610 is not set
CONFIG_GPIO_XGENE=y
CONFIG_GPIO_XGENE_SB=m
# CONFIG_GPIO_XILINX is not set
CONFIG_GPIO_XLP=y
CONFIG_GPIO_ZYNQ=m
CONFIG_GPIO_ZYNQMP_MODEPIN=y
# CONFIG_GPIO_AMD_FCH is not set
# end of Memory mapped GPIO drivers

Here is the content of /boot/efi/config.txt:
arm_64bit=1
enable_uart=1
uart_2ndstage=1
enable_gic=1
armstub=RPI_EFI.fd
disable_commandline_tags=1
disable_overscan=1
device_tree_address=0x1f0000
device_tree_end=0x200000
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
dtoverlay=upstream-pi4

I don't know where to go from that.

Is switching to the latest version of raspbian (or whatever it is called these days) to get a kernel allowing what you want to do, an option?

If I can get the GPIO working on Debian, it's not worth the hassle to setup again the whole server (I'm using the Rpi as a a server) by switching to Rapberry Pi OS.

I have not researched this but You probably need to build a new kernel

Does your server have the backup+restore procedure in place?

As others have noted, support for sysfs has been (mostly) deprecated since ver. 6.6 of the Linux kernel was introduced in 'bookworm'. You can still get sysfs access by "dropping back" to the 'bullseye' distro. And I am TL;DR the tutorial you followed, but it's several years old now.
There has been much debate regarding the options available for GPIO control. The designated successor to sysfs is libgpiod, but it has, in general, received very mixed reviews. It is available for 'bookworm' through Debian channels.
As you are running a Debian distro on your RPi 4, I'm not clear on what your options are for GPIO programming - or even if you have any options. Apparently the folks at Debian aren't clear on this either as their wiki is badly out-of-date; same goes for much of the rest of their documentation on Raspberry Pi. Debian does provide a libgpiod package, but it's unclear whether it's included in their RPi4 distro - or for that matter whether GPIO works on RPi4 at all under Debian!. If there is a configuration setting, or a "magic switch" that's required to enable GPIO under Debian... I think they are doing a fair job of keeping that a secret.
If the tutorial you followed addresses any of this uncertainty/out-of-date docs perhaps you should continue following it. If not, and if using GPIO is a priority - I would have to suggest that maybe it's time to install some version of RPi OS (née Raspbian).
I don't know what led you to choose Debian over RPiOS, but I believe it offers more and better options for GPIO programming. For example, one package that I've used recently (and rather like) is called pinctrl. It was developed by the RPi team (perhaps in response to the unpopularity of libgpiod), and is both fast and efficient. Another is wiringPi - an older favorite that fell into disrepair, but has recently come under "new management"... and there are a few others.
Another point to make wrt Debian vs RPiOS is that Debian may not support the RPi's device tree (I recall reading this, but can't find the reference now). If true, this means that under Debian you won't have access to the many dtoverlays that simplify GPIO usage.

Unfortunately gpiod doesn't seem to detect anything as gpioinfo doesn't output anything. If there is an issue with the device tree, where can I get more info/logs? dmesg is not really helpful. I would love to see an error message somewhere that would explain the issue, because for now there is only silence from the OS.

@Cl00e9ment: I don't understand why Debian would offer the libgpiod package if it didn't work at all - that doesn't sound right, but I'm afraid my best suggestion is to check with the folks on the Debian forum. I just did some more research & edited my answer to reflect my findings - you might want to re-read it. I assume you are aware that Debian offers their own installation instructions for Raspberry Pi: here, and also here?

sysfs GPIO support (if it ever worked on Debian kernel) has been deprecated for years and finally removed.

While libgpiod/gpiod is supported by most Linux distros of itself it does nothing. The libraries REQUIRE GPIO drivers to interface with the particular hardware.
It is unlikely a generic Debian would have support for the Pi hardware. Raspberry Pi OS has Pi specific drivers in its kernel and the Debian OS for Pi probably does (but I have not tried, although I have heard it exists).
If you want GPIO use an OS designed for Pi.

OK I didn't knew. Anyway I also checked with gpiod and gpioinfo doesn't output anything.

The kernel need to have the necessary code to do this

Try to manually load the GPIO module: sudo modprobe gpio-generic
If it gives an error, there might be an issue with the module or its dependencies.

Not only I'm using the Debian Kernel, but I also installed Debian with a UEFI which mean that hardware discovery is done using ACPI and not a device tree.
From what I understand, this is why it doesn't work. The README of the Raspberry Pi 4 UEFI Firmware Images even say:

Many drivers (GPIO, VPU, etc) are still likely to be missing from your OS, and will have to be provided by a third party.

I could configure the UEFI to boot with a device tree instead of ACPI, but I was not able to boot to the OS successfully that way. I also tested the Debian pre-built images which use a device tree, and GPIO worked. I was not able to make the PWM work though.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
